# CameraX configuration issue in oppo A5 version 11

Tags: android, configuration, camera, android-camerax, oppo

Facing issue while configuration cameraX in oppo A5 , android version 11 works fine on all other devices.

Dependencies used:

// CameraX core library
def camerax_version = '1.1.0-beta01'

// CameraX Camera2 extensions
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"

// CameraX Lifecycle library
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"

// CameraX View class
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:$camerax_version"

**CameraFragment Class :**

```
typealias LumaListener = (luma: Double) -> Unit

class CameraFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _fragmentCameraBinding: FragmentCameraBinding? = null

    private val fragmentCameraBinding get() = _fragmentCameraBinding!!

    private var cameraUiContainerBinding: CameraUiContainerBinding? = null

    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var broadcastManager: LocalBroadcastManager

    private var displayId: Int = -1
    private var lensFacing: Int = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
    private var preview: Preview? = null
    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private var imageAnalyzer: ImageAnalysis? = null
    private var camera: Camera? = null
    private var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider? = null
    private lateinit var windowManager: WindowManager

    private val displayManager by lazy {
        requireContext().getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager
    }

    /** Blocking camera operations are performed using this executor */
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    

    


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        _fragmentCameraBinding = null
        super.onDestroyView()

        // Shut down our background executor
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()

        // Unregister the broadcast receivers and listeners
        broadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(volumeDownReceiver)
        displayManager.unregisterDisplayListener(displayListener)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _fragmentCameraBinding = FragmentCameraBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return fragmentCameraBinding.root
    }

    private fun setGalleryThumbnail(uri: Uri) {
        // Run the operations in the view's thread
        cameraUiContainerBinding?.photoViewButton?.let { photoViewButton ->
            photoViewButton.post {
                // Remove thumbnail padding
                //photoViewButton.setPadding(resources.getDimension(R.dimen.stroke_small).toInt())

                // Load thumbnail into circular button using Glide
                Glide.with(photoViewButton)
                        .load(uri)
                        .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                        .into(photoViewButton)
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Initialize our background executor
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

        broadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(view.context)

        // Set up the intent filter that will receive events from our main activity
        val filter = IntentFilter().apply { addAction(KEY_EVENT_ACTION) }
        broadcastManager.registerReceiver(volumeDownReceiver, filter)

        // Every time the orientation of device changes, update rotation for use cases
        displayManager.registerDisplayListener(displayListener, null)

        //Initialize WindowManager to retrieve display metrics
        windowManager = WindowManager(view.context)

        // Determine the output directory
        outputDirectory = MainActivity.getOutputDirectory(requireContext())

        // Wait for the views to be properly laid out
        fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.post {

            // Keep track of the display in which this view is attached
            displayId = fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.display.displayId

            // Build UI controls
            updateCameraUi()

            // Set up the camera and its use cases
            setUpCamera()
        }
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)

        // Rebind the camera with the updated display metrics
        bindCameraUseCases()

        // Enable or disable switching between cameras
        updateCameraSwitchButton()
    }

    /** Initialize CameraX, and prepare to bind the camera use cases  */
    private fun setUpCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext())
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {

            // CameraProvider
            cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            Log.e(TAG,"cameraProvider")

            // Select lensFacing depending on the available cameras
            lensFacing = when {
                hasBackCamera() -> CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
                hasFrontCamera() -> CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("Back and front camera are unavailable")
            }

            // Enable or disable switching between cameras
            updateCameraSwitchButton()

            // Build and bind the camera use cases
            bindCameraUseCases()
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()))
    }

    /** Declare and bind preview, capture and analysis use cases */
    private fun bindCameraUseCases() {

        // Get screen metrics used to setup camera for full screen resolution
        val metrics = windowManager.getCurrentWindowMetrics().bounds
        Log.d(TAG, "Screen metrics: ${metrics.width()} x ${metrics.height()}")

        val screenAspectRatio = aspectRatio(metrics.width(), metrics.height())
        Log.d(TAG, "Preview aspect ratio: $screenAspectRatio")

        val rotation = fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.display.rotation

        // CameraProvider
        val cameraProvider = cameraProvider
                ?: throw IllegalStateException("Camera initialization failed.")

        // CameraSelector
        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(lensFacing).build()

        // Preview
        preview = Preview.Builder()
                // We request aspect ratio but no resolution
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                // Set initial target rotation
                .setTargetRotation(rotation)
                .build()

        // ImageCapture
        imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                // We request aspect ratio but no resolution to match preview config, but letting
                // CameraX optimize for whatever specific resolution best fits our use cases
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
                // during the lifecycle of this use case
                .setTargetRotation(rotation)
                .build()

        // ImageAnalysis
        imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                // We request aspect ratio but no resolution
                .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
                // Set initial target rotation, we will have to call this again if rotation changes
                // during the lifecycle of this use case
                .setTargetRotation(rotation)
                .build()
                // The analyzer can then be assigned to the instance
                .also {
                    it.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, LuminosityAnalyzer { luma ->
                        // Values returned from our analyzer are passed to the attached listener
                        // We log image analysis results here - you should do something useful
                        // instead!
                        Log.d(TAG, "Average luminosity: $luma")
                    })
                }

        // Must unbind the use-cases before rebinding them
        cameraProvider.unbindAll()

        try {
            // A variable number of use-cases can be passed here -
            // camera provides access to CameraControl & CameraInfo
            camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                    this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture, imageAnalyzer)

            // Attach the viewfinder's surface provider to preview use case
            preview?.setSurfaceProvider(fragmentCameraBinding.viewFinder.surfaceProvider)
            observeCameraState(camera?.cameraInfo!!)
        } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }
    }

    private fun observeCameraState(cameraInfo: CameraInfo) {
        cameraInfo.cameraState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { cameraState ->
            run {
                when (cameraState.type) {
                    CameraState.Type.PENDING_OPEN -> {
                        // Ask the user to close other camera apps
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "CameraState: Pending Open",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    CameraState.Type.OPENING -> {
                        // Show the Camera UI
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "CameraState: Opening",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    CameraState.Type.OPEN -> {
                        // Setup Camera resources and begin processing
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "CameraState: Open",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    CameraState.Type.CLOSING -> {
                        // Close camera UI
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "CameraState: Closing",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    CameraState.Type.CLOSED -> {
                        // Free camera resources
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "CameraState: Closed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }

            cameraState.error?.let { error ->
                when (error.code) {
                    // Open errors
                    CameraState.ERROR_STREAM_CONFIG -> {
                        // Make sure to setup the use cases properly
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Stream config error",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    // Opening errors
                    CameraState.ERROR_CAMERA_IN_USE -> {
                        // Close the camera or ask user to close another camera app that's using the
                        // camera
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Camera in use",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    CameraState.ERROR_MAX_CAMERAS_IN_USE -> {
                        // Close another open camera in the app, or ask the user to close another
                        // camera app that's using the camera
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Max cameras in use",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    CameraState.ERROR_OTHER_RECOVERABLE_ERROR -> {
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Other recoverable error",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    // Closing errors
                    CameraState.ERROR_CAMERA_DISABLED -> {
                        // Ask the user to enable the device's cameras
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Camera disabled",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    CameraState.ERROR_CAMERA_FATAL_ERROR -> {
                        // Ask the user to reboot the device to restore camera function
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Fatal error",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    // Closed errors
                    CameraState.ERROR_DO_NOT_DISTURB_MODE_ENABLED -> {
                        // Ask the user to disable the "Do Not Disturb" mode, then reopen the camera
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Do not disturb mode enabled",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    
    private fun aspectRatio(width: Int, height: Int): Int {
        val previewRatio = max(width, height).toDouble() / min(width, height)
        if (abs(previewRatio - RATIO_4_3_VALUE) <= abs(previewRatio - RATIO_16_9_VALUE)) {
            return AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3
        }
        return AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9
    }

    /** Method used to re-draw the camera UI controls, called every time configuration changes. */
    private fun updateCameraUi() {

        // Remove previous UI if any
        cameraUiContainerBinding?.root?.let {
            fragmentCameraBinding.root.removeView(it)
        }

        cameraUiContainerBinding = CameraUiContainerBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()),
                fragmentCameraBinding.root,
                true
        )

        // In the background, load latest photo taken (if any) for gallery thumbnail
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            outputDirectory.listFiles { file ->
                EXTENSION_WHITELIST.contains(file.extension.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT))
            }?.maxOrNull()?.let {
                setGalleryThumbnail(Uri.fromFile(it))
            }
        }

        // Listener for button used to capture photo
        cameraUiContainerBinding?.cameraCaptureButton?.setOnClickListener {

            // Get a stable reference of the modifiable image capture use case
            imageCapture?.let { imageCapture ->

                // Create output file to hold the image
                val photoFile = createFile(outputDirectory, FILENAME, PHOTO_EXTENSION)

                // Setup image capture metadata
                val metadata = Metadata().apply {

                    // Mirror image when using the front camera
                    isReversedHorizontal = lensFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
                }

                // Create output options object which contains file + metadata
                val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile)
                        .setMetadata(metadata)
                        .build()

                // Setup image capture listener which is triggered after photo has been taken
                imageCapture.takePicture(
                        outputOptions, cameraExecutor, object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                    override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Photo capture failed: ${exc.message}", exc)
                    }

                    override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                        val savedUri = output.savedUri ?: Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                        Log.d(TAG, "Photo capture succeeded: $savedUri")

                        // We can only change the foreground Drawable using API level 23+ API
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                            // Update the gallery thumbnail with latest picture taken
                            setGalleryThumbnail(savedUri)
                        }

                        // Implicit broadcasts will be ignored for devices running API level >= 24
                        // so if you only target API level 24+ you can remove this statement
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            requireActivity().sendBroadcast(
                                    Intent(android.hardware.Camera.ACTION_NEW_PICTURE, savedUri)
                            )
                        }

                        // If the folder selected is an external media directory, this is
                        // unnecessary but otherwise other apps will not be able to access our
                        // images unless we scan them using [MediaScannerConnection]
                        val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
                                .getMimeTypeFromExtension(savedUri.toFile().extension)
                        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
                                context,
                                arrayOf(savedUri.toFile().absolutePath),
                                arrayOf(mimeType)
                        ) { _, uri ->
                            Log.d(TAG, "Image capture scanned into media store: $uri")
                        }
                    }
                })

                // We can only change the foreground Drawable using API level 23+ API
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

                    // Display flash animation to indicate that photo was captured
                    fragmentCameraBinding.root.postDelayed({
                        fragmentCameraBinding.root.foreground = ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE)
                        fragmentCameraBinding.root.postDelayed(
                                { fragmentCameraBinding.root.foreground = null }, ANIMATION_FAST_MILLIS
                        )
                    }, ANIMATION_SLOW_MILLIS)
                }
            }
        }

        // Setup for button used to switch cameras
        cameraUiContainerBinding?.cameraSwitchButton?.let {

            // Disable the button until the camera is set up
            it.isEnabled = false

            // Listener for button used to switch cameras. Only called if the button is enabled
            it.setOnClickListener {
                lensFacing = if (CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT == lensFacing) {
                    CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
                } else {
                    CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
                }
                // Re-bind use cases to update selected camera
                bindCameraUseCases()
            }
        }

        // Listener for button used to view the most recent photo
        cameraUiContainerBinding?.photoViewButton?.setOnClickListener {
            // Only navigate when the gallery has photos
            if (true == outputDirectory.listFiles()?.isNotEmpty()) {
                Navigation.findNavController(
                        requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container
                ).navigate(
                    CameraFragmentDirections.actionCameraToGallery(
                        outputDirectory.absolutePath
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }

    private fun updateCameraSwitchButton() {
        try {
            cameraUiContainerBinding?.cameraSwitchButton?.isEnabled = hasBackCamera() && hasFrontCamera()
        } catch (exception: CameraInfoUnavailableException) {
            cameraUiContainerBinding?.cameraSwitchButton?.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    /** Returns true if the device has an available back camera. False otherwise */
    private fun hasBackCamera(): Boolean {
        return cameraProvider?.hasCamera(CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA) ?: false
    }

    /** Returns true if the device has an available front camera. False otherwise */
    private fun hasFrontCamera(): Boolean {
        return cameraProvider?.hasCamera(CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA) ?: false
    }

   
    private class LuminosityAnalyzer(listener: LumaListener? = null) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
        private val frameRateWindow = 8
        private val frameTimestamps = ArrayDeque<Long>(5)
        private val listeners = ArrayList<LumaListener>().apply { listener?.let { add(it) } }
        private var lastAnalyzedTimestamp = 0L
        var framesPerSecond: Double = -1.0
            private set

        fun onFrameAnalyzed(listener: LumaListener) = listeners.add(listener)

        private fun ByteBuffer.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
            rewind()    // Rewind the buffer to zero
            val data = ByteArray(remaining())
            get(data)   // Copy the buffer into a byte array
            return data // Return the byte array
        }

       
        override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
            // If there are no listeners attached, we don't need to perform analysis
            if (listeners.isEmpty()) {
                image.close()
                return
            }

            // Keep track of frames analyzed
            val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            frameTimestamps.push(currentTime)

            // Compute the FPS using a moving average
            while (frameTimestamps.size >= frameRateWindow) frameTimestamps.removeLast()
            val timestampFirst = frameTimestamps.peekFirst() ?: currentTime
            val timestampLast = frameTimestamps.peekLast() ?: currentTime
            framesPerSecond = 1.0 / ((timestampFirst - timestampLast) /
                    frameTimestamps.size.coerceAtLeast(1).toDouble()) * 1000.0

            // Analysis could take an arbitrarily long amount of time
            // Since we are running in a different thread, it won't stall other use cases

            lastAnalyzedTimestamp = frameTimestamps.first

            // Since format in ImageAnalysis is YUV, image.planes[0] contains the luminance plane
            val buffer = image.planes[0].buffer

            // Extract image data from callback object
            val data = buffer.toByteArray()

            // Convert the data into an array of pixel values ranging 0-255
            val pixels = data.map { it.toInt() and 0xFF }

            // Compute average luminance for the image
            val luma = pixels.average()

            // Call all listeners with new value
            listeners.forEach { it(luma) }

            image.close()
        }
    }

    companion object {

        private const val TAG = "CameraXBasic"
        private const val FILENAME = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
        private const val PHOTO_EXTENSION = ".jpg"
        private const val RATIO_4_3_VALUE = 4.0 / 3.0
        private const val RATIO_16_9_VALUE = 16.0 / 9.0

        /** Helper function used to create a timestamped file */
        private fun createFile(baseFolder: File, format: String, extension: String) =
                File(baseFolder, SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US)
                        .format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + extension)
    }
}
```

**camera_fragment.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/camera_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/view_finder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**camera_ui_container.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/camera_ui_container"
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Camera control and gallery buttons -->
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/camera_switch_button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_switch"
    android:contentDescription="@string/switch_camera_button_alt" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/camera_capture_button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_large"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_large"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_shutter"
    android:contentDescription="@string/capture_button_alt" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/photo_view_button"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/round_button_medium"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/round_button_medium"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_photo"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/gallery_button_alt" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**
After lots of work final got the solution,
This is because of large application id, My id was based on **75 characters**.
when i reduce it to **60 characters** its work fine.